# Retrieve REDIRECT_STATUS with error_page

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, http-status

Using `.htaccess` and `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php`, if access an invalid url eg.: `http://example/css/invalid-file.css`:

```
<?php
echo 'REDIRECT_STATUS: ', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'], PHP_EOL,
     'REDIRECT_URL: ', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], PHP_EOL,
     'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD: ', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Output:

```
REDIRECT_STATUS: 404
REDIRECT_URL: /css/invalid-file.css
REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD: GET
```

But in Nginx using `error_page 404 /error.php;` this is not working, the result in Nginx is:

```
REDIRECT_STATUS: 200
REDIRECT_URL: 
REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD:
```

> Note: REDIRECT_URL and REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD are undefineds

How to set the variables `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_STATUS]`, `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD]` and `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_URL]` using [Ngnix](http://nginx.org)?

**fastcgi_params file:**

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED         $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

Comment: What does [http_response_code()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) return?

Comment: What does your FastCGI config say for `REDIRECT_STATUS`?  I bet it's hard coded to `200`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix it in Nginx, you need to create a fake `location`.

Example:

```
# Set fake location for 404
error_page 404 @fakeroute404;

# Access fake location
location @fakeroute404 {
    ...# Others needed settings

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include fastcgi params

    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD "GET"; # Set HTTP method
    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 404;  # Set HTTP status
    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_URL $uri;    # Set REDIRECT_URL
}
```